# Displaying current date with CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

I have used a script for datepicker like below

```
<script> 
$(function() { 
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'});
$('.timepicker').timepicker({ timeFormat: 'H:mm:ss p' });

 });
 </script>
```

And this displays a datepicker in text field for

```
      <div class="bit-4 pad-small">
      <label>Trip Date</label>
          <?php echo $this->Form->input('trip_date',             array('label'=>false,'type' =>  'text','placeholder'=>'','maxlength'=>'30','class' =>  'datepicker','required'));  ?>
    <span>required</span>
  </div>
```

But I want the current date to be displayed automatically in the date column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the value to current date using php `date()` function. For formatting options you can see the following link:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

I think this code will help you

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('trip_date',array('label'=>false,'type' =>'text','placeholder'=>'','maxlength'=>'30','class'=>'datepicker','required','value'=>date('Y-m-d')));
```

Comment: Although your answer looks correct to me, it might help the OP if you explain what you've done and why, so the OP can learn something from it, rather than just copy/paste this code.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `default` attribute rather than the `value` attribute to set the default value of the input:-

```
<?php 
    echo $this->Form->input('trip_date',array(
        'label' => false,
        'type' => 'text',
        'placeholder' => '',
        'maxlength' => '30',
        'class' => 'datepicker',
        'required',
        'default' => date('Y-m-d')
    )); 
?>
```

If you use `value` it will override any form data passed via `$this->request->data` which is generally not what is wanted. `default` provides a value for the input if one has not been passed via `$this->request->data`. If you use Tanbir Sagar's suggestion then if you have a situation where there is a validation error in your form data your `trip_date` field would be reset to the current date each time.